Calls to storage.googleapis.com suddenly getting "Connection reset by peer" (but not in Browser)
Some change has happened recently with some of google's APIs. Suddenly, requests made while on my work network all fail during the TLS handshake with a "Connection reset by peer". The odd thing is that it's only on that network (which would mean it's likely that the network firewall is borking things) and that the same request DOES work in a browser.
What can i do to a) work around this issue + go back to making successful requests or b) figure out exactly what needs to be changed in the network so i can tell the heartless IT people what needs to be fixed?
Here's a trace of a basic failure from curl https://storage.googleapis.com
09:35:04.184999 [0-0] == Info: Host storage.googleapis.com:443 was resolved.
09:35:04.185149 [0-0] == Info: IPv6: 2a00:1450:4028:809::201b, 2a00:1450:4028:805::201b, 2a00:1450:4028:800::201b, 2a00:1450:4028:804::201b
09:35:04.185154 [0-0] == Info: IPv4: 142.250.75.123, 142.250.75.59, 142.251.142.219, 142.250.75.91, 142.250.75.155
09:35:04.185161 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] added
09:35:04.185165 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, init
09:35:04.185168 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, check h21
09:35:04.185173 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] created ipv4 (timeout 149960ms)
09:35:04.185176 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] created ipv6 (timeout 149960ms)
09:35:04.185181 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] ipv4 starting (timeout=149960ms)
09:35:04.185199 [0-0] == Info:   Trying 142.250.75.123:443...
09:35:04.185211 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] cf_socket_open() -> 0, fd=6
09:35:04.185259 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] local address 192.168.2.70 port 40000...
09:35:04.185263 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] ipv4 connect -> 0, connected=0
09:35:04.185266 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.185272 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.185274 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.185277 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.185280 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.185283 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.185285 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.188859 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, check h21
09:35:04.188881 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] connected
09:35:04.188884 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] ipv4 connect -> 0, connected=1
09:35:04.188893 [0-0] == Info: Connected to storage.googleapis.com (142.250.75.123) port 443
09:35:04.188899 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect()
09:35:04.191304 [0-0] == Info: ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
09:35:04.191521 [0-0] => Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: 16 03 01 02 00                                  .....
09:35:04.191573 [0-0] == Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
09:35:04.191576 [0-0] => Send SSL data, 512 bytes (0x200)
0000: 01 00 01 fc 03 03 c6 7c f6 e2 54 24 20 fc 2c 90 .......|..T$ .,.
0010: d5 ed 13 77 5f e1 0d e8 e7 ba 64 ca 2a 53 b5 41 ...w_.....d.*S.A
0020: 6c bd 20 c4 ca 2d 20 5a f3 4d 7d 19 c5 f6 c8 de l. ..- Z.M}.....
0030: 4d a8 75 af 71 3c ba d6 cf ae 4c ca 72 38 47 cd M.u.q<....L.r8G.
0040: 2d 42 b1 3a 53 a6 86 00 3e 13 02 13 03 13 01 c0 -B.:S...>.......
0050: 2c c0 30 00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa c0 2b c0 2f 00 ,.0.........+./.
0060: 9e c0 24 c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27 00 67 c0 0a c0 ..$.(.k.#.'.g...
0070: 14 00 39 c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d 00 9c 00 3d 00 ..9.....3.....=.
0080: 3c 00 35 00 2f 00 ff 01 00 01 75 00 00 00 1b 00 <.5./.....u.....
0090: 19 00 00 16 73 74 6f 72 61 67 65 2e 67 6f 6f 67 ....storage.goog
00a0: 6c 65 61 70 69 73 2e 63 6f 6d 00 0b 00 04 03 00 leapis.com......
00b0: 01 02 00 0a 00 16 00 14 00 1d 00 17 00 1e 00 19 ................
00c0: 00 18 01 00 01 01 01 02 01 03 01 04 00 10 00 0e ................
00d0: 00 0c 02 68 32 08 68 74 74 70 2f 31 2e 31 00 16 ...h2.http/1.1..
00e0: 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 31 00 00 00 0d 00 2a 00 28 .......1.....*.(
00f0: 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08 08 08 09 08 0a 08 0b ................
0100: 08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01 05 01 06 01 03 03 03 01 ................
0110: 03 02 04 02 05 02 06 02 00 2b 00 05 04 03 04 03 .........+......
0120: 03 00 2d 00 02 01 01 00 33 00 26 00 24 00 1d 00 ..-.....3.&.$...
0130: 20 33 d2 28 23 9d a6 21 3e f0 86 81 54 e1 7c 26  3.(#..!>...T.|&
0140: 6f a4 d2 75 36 ab 90 e1 7b af b8 41 fc 08 05 c3 o..u6...{..A....
0150: 28 00 15 00 ab 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (...............
0160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
0170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
0180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
0190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
01a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
01b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
01c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
01d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
01e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
01f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
09:35:04.191720 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] send(len=517) -> 517, err=0
09:35:04.191723 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_out_write(len=517) -> 517, err=0
09:35:04.191730 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] nw_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.191733 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] recv(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.191736 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.229637 [0-0] == Info:  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
09:35:04.229641 [0-0] == Info:  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
09:35:04.229645 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect() -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.229647 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.229652 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.229654 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.229656 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.229658 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.233721 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, check h21
09:35:04.233723 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect()
09:35:04.233731 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] nw_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.233733 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] recv(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.233736 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.233738 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect() -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.233740 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.233743 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.233745 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.233746 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.233748 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.235808 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, check h21
09:35:04.235810 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect()
09:35:04.235815 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] nw_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.235817 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] recv(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.235819 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=81
09:35:04.235821 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect() -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.235823 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect -> 0, done=0
09:35:04.235826 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.235827 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.235829 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.235831 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] adjust_pollset -> 1 socks
09:35:04.248918 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, check h21
09:35:04.248919 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect()
09:35:04.249021 [0-0] == Info: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
09:35:04.249023 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] nw_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=56
09:35:04.249025 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] recv(len=5) -> -1, err=56
09:35:04.249027 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_in_read(len=5) -> -1, err=56
09:35:04.249035 [0-0] == Info: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443 
09:35:04.249038 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] cf_connect() -> 35, done=0
09:35:04.249040 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect, all failed
09:35:04.249041 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] connect -> 35, done=0
09:35:04.249047 [0-0] == Info: Closing connection
09:35:04.249049 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] close
09:35:04.249051 [0-0] == Info: [SETUP] close
09:35:04.249056 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] nw_in_read(len=5) -> 0, err=0
09:35:04.249057 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] recv(len=5) -> 0, err=0
09:35:04.249059 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_in_read(len=5) -> 0, err=0
09:35:04.249064 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] nw_in_read(len=5) -> 0, err=0
09:35:04.249066 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] recv(len=5) -> 0, err=0
09:35:04.249067 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] ossl_bio_cf_in_read(len=5) -> 0, err=0
09:35:04.249071 [0-0] == Info: [SSL] SSL shutdown, error: 'SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL', errno 0
09:35:04.249590 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] close
09:35:04.249592 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] cf_socket_close(6)
09:35:04.249609 [0-0] == Info: [TCP] destroy
09:35:04.249611 [0-0] == Info: [HAPPY-EYEBALLS] destroy
09:35:04.249613 [0-0] == Info: [SETUP] destroy
09:35:04.249615 [0-0] == Info: [HTTPS-CONNECT] destroy

Any guidance would be appreciated.

The remote server has sent you a RST packet, which indicates an immediate dropping of the connection, rather than the usual handshake.It might be a TCP/IP issue you need to resolve with your host or upgrade your OS. Most times the connection is closed with the remote server before it finishes downloading the content resulting in “Connection reset by peer”.

Please be noted that curl sometimes has issues with SSL and SSL certificates. And I don't think that OpenSSL was installed in your web server. Anyways, try installing Open SSL on the server and try again and that should help you get rid of this error. Also please refer to this.

It is unclear just from this description what exactly is causing the issue. There is likely some DPI (deep packet inspection interferring) with the traffic. But this can be done by an endpoint solution local on each client or be a feature of the corporate firewall or similar. And it might be based on TLS fingerprinting to allow browsers or browsers access the internet to an explicit proxy, i.e. with a different path. Since nothing is known about your environment no recommendation can be given of what exactly needs to be fixed.

@ImranPremnawaz: None of your recommendations make any sense in my opinion:  The OP is accessing a Google server, not their own. And it works with the browser. And the RST happens before any certificates are sent by the server, so it cannot be about curl having problems with the certificates.

@SteffenUllrich you're right, it's not curl bc the same call works when I'm on a different network. The issue is that I don't have control over the network, so I'm also blind as to what the issue is.  Part of the question is what can I do to help pinpoint the issue. I know it occurs on multiple hosts and multiple OSes, and also only on the one network. Is there something more specific I can point to so I can get the IT ppl who don't care to fix it?

Like I said, there is some DPI inspection somewhere. IT personal should know where it is - so tell them your problem. Also, they might have configured it on purpose to block access.
